# Rendering Rich text htmls in an application and yet prevent XSS attacks (possibilites and approaches)

Tags: javascript, html, css, security, xss

I am having a peculiar problem. I am working on an application where we store the html rich content. And then render it in an Iframe. I have multiple questions in this area.

1. when loading and rendering rich content like this, is there a possibility of XSS attacks? If yes, then what kind of attacks shall these be?
2. If answer to above question is yes, then how should I prevent it?

Currently we are using JSOP library to strip the html tags from the content and sending it to server for rendering. Is there a way to retain the CSS and style attributes and still have my application secure against XSS attacks in my particular situation? (NOTE: I am just rendering the content; user is not entering any data here; at least not in the whole process; though there might be a possibility that original data at first place has malicious contnet). Effectively is there any other way for me except using whitelist or blacklist (of tags) based solution ?

What I have looked so far are below.

- sanitize library : configurable white list based
- antisamy: configurable
- owasp java html sanitizer: configurable white list based
- jsoup library : configurable white list based
- owasp: a good reference
- encoding: only for user input. I don't think its relevant for my use case here.
- content-security-policy: seems like a usable thing along with
  jsoup/sanitize like solution

In a nutshell, What I need is CSS and styling to remain the same, rest I can block.

Resources I have gone through are: [owasp](https://www.owasp.org/) [salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting) [this article](http://excess-xss.com/#xss-prevention)

Comment: Anybody ? Any help ?